# I want to make a Doughnut with rounded edges of chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Copy the two codes and enter them in the code pen, and the chart and percentage will appear separately.
I want the percentage to be in the middle of the chart.
I'm studying html and css, so it's hard to understand the javascript source, so I'm asking.
These codes were put by referring to the stackoverflow.
thanks

```js
Chart.defaults.RoundedDoughnut = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.doughnut);
Chart.controllers.RoundedDoughnut = Chart.controllers.doughnut.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
    var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;

    var easingDecimal = ease || 1;
    Chart.helpers.each(this.getDataset().metaData, function(arc, index) {
      arc.transition(easingDecimal).draw();

      var vm = arc._view;
      var radius = (vm.outerRadius + vm.innerRadius) / 2;
      var thickness = (vm.outerRadius - vm.innerRadius) / 2;
      var angle = Math.PI - vm.endAngle - Math.PI / 2;

      ctx.save();
      ctx.fillStyle = vm.backgroundColor;
      ctx.translate(vm.x, vm.y);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(radius * Math.sin(angle), radius * Math.cos(angle), thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.arc(radius * Math.sin(Math.PI), radius * Math.cos(Math.PI), thickness, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    });
  },
});

var deliveredData = {
  labels: [
    "Value"
  ],
  datasets: [{
    data: [70, 30],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#3ec556",
      "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "#3ec556",
      "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
    ],
    borderWidth: [
      0, 0
    ]
  }]
};

var deliveredOpt = {
  cutoutPercentage: 88,
  animation: {
    animationRotate: true,
    duration: 2000
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  tooltips: {
    enabled: false
  }
};

var chart = new Chart($('#openedCanvas'), {
  type: 'RoundedDoughnut',
  data: deliveredData,
  options: deliveredOpt
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mychart.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal-div-canvas js-chart">
    <div class="chart-canvas">
      <canvas id="openedCanvas" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
      <div class="chart-background"></div>
      <span class="chart-unique-value">
                   <span class="js-count">
                      85
                   </span>
      <span class="cuv-percent">%</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <canvas id="openedCanvas" height="230" width="680"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```